# Complicated integral involving Dirac delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

How can I solve this integral ?

It involves two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, as well as derivative according to $x$ and the Dirac delta function.

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \frac{d}{dx} \delta(x-R)g(x) dx 
$$

Comment: Integrate by parts to move the derivative from $\delta$ to $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 2):

Using IBP we get that:
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)g(x){d\delta(x-R)}=\left[f(x)g(x)\delta(x-R)\right]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\left[f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)\right]\delta(x-R)dx$$
Can you finish it from here?